# Struct method as goroutine with access to struct members

Tags: go, concurrency

1. Is there anything wrong with using methods as goroutines this way?
2. Do I need a mutex on data if Work() method only reads?
3. Is there a better pattern I can use to implement this kind of service.

```
type Worker struct {
    data string
}

func (w *Worker) fetchData() {
    for {
        // sleep for defined period of time
        // fetch the data
        w.data = fetched_data
    }
}

func (w *Worker) Work() {
    go w.fetchData()
    for {
        // do some work that reads w.data
    }
}

func main() {
    worker := Worker{"data"}
    worker.Work()
}
```

Comment: 2: Yes. Your code has a potential memory race because you have concurrent read and write of `w.data`. You cannot safely read and write the same value concurrently.

Comment: Each time the "data" is fetched, how many times do you need to do "Work" on it?

Comment: The work loop is fast, assume in the range of 10-300 iterations / s, fetchData loop runs once every 1-15 minutes. So mutex is the way to go here? Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Mutex is enough to make the memory access safe. If you want to encode any logic about the sequencing of events, then you should use a channel to send data from `fetchData` to `Work`.